# using selenium I have to re-login everytime I navigate from one page to another

Tags: selenium, saucelabs

When the tests navigate from one page to another, selenium IE webdriver always has to re-login. Does anyone know why? It logs in the first time, but then has to re-login when it navigates to a different page. This only happens in IE and not Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Can you try manually by navigating url ?

Comment: The session is lost from one page to the next. There could be a hundred reasons for why this is happening. I would suggest you consult with your developer to narrow the problem down.